# How do I programmatically compile a C# Windows Forms App from a richtextbox? C#

Tags: c#, visual-studio, compilation

I am trying to do a Visual Studio kind of program, which allows you to type code into a RichTextBox. After pressing F5(Compile), it would compile the code. How would the user compile said code? I know how to use the ConsoleApplication Compiler, but not compiling Windows Forms :(

Could someone help? A code-example is preferable, but at this point, I'll accept **ANYTHING!**

My current code for Console Apps is this:

```
        CSharpCodeProvider codeProvider = new CSharpCodeProvider();
        ICodeCompiler icc = codeProvider.CreateCompiler();
        string Output = "MCCACOut.exe";
            Button ButtonObject = (Button)sender;

            richTextBox201.Text = "";
            System.CodeDom.Compiler.CompilerParameters parameters = new CompilerParameters();
            //Make sure we generate an EXE, not a DLL
            parameters.GenerateExecutable = true;
            parameters.OutputAssembly = Output;
            CompilerResults results = icc.CompileAssemblyFromSource(parameters, richTextBox301.Text);

            if (results.Errors.Count > 0)
            {
                richTextBox201.ForeColor = Color.Red;
                foreach (CompilerError CompErr in results.Errors)
                {
                    richTextBox201.Text = richTextBox201.Text +
                                "Line number " + CompErr.Line +
                                ", Error Number: " + CompErr.ErrorNumber +
                                ", '" + CompErr.ErrorText + ";" +
                                Environment.NewLine + Environment.NewLine;
                }
            }
            else
            {
                //Successful Compile
                richTextBox201.ForeColor = Color.Blue;
                richTextBox201.Text = "Success!";
                //If we clicked run then launch our EXE
                Process.Start(Output);
            }
```

Could anyone convert this to compile WinForms instead of ConsoleApp? :)

Comment: Look up how to build c# apps from commandline.. then run that.

Comment: No results matching my description(or yours) came up.(Google, StackOverFlow, etc.) All they say is "From CommandPrompt/Notepad" but that is not what I want... I need it to compile straight from richtextbox and create output .exe, and it should compile as WindowsForms.

Comment: Do you have any example code, or know anyone who could help? I am struggling :(

Comment: First Link when Googling `msbuild winforms`: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/708029/command-line-compiling-a-win-forms-c-sharp-application

Comment: It didn't explain exactly HOW to use it :..( it only explained WHAT to use... I appreciate the link though :) is there any way to compile a Windows Forms App like the code I just provided in the question, but obviously differently?

Comment: "I'll accept anything - unless it doesn't explain exactly how to use it"? You are missing the point in the article you copied the code from: the only distinction that is drawn is wether to compile to a dll or exe. The compiler simply does not care wether it is compiling a Console-, Winforms-, or WPF-App. Thats the codes responsibility. To investigate the differences create a Console- and WinForms-App in Visual-Studio and compare the resulting solutions.

Comment: So, how would I code it to compile Winform? If it's the code's responsibility, then how would I code it to do so?

Comment: It has nothing to do with the code your provided above! The code inputted into the textbox has to be "Winform-code" (e.g. referencing winform-assemblies, calling winform-methods...)

Comment: I know it doesn't involve the code(Now!), but even if I compile with "Winform-Code", it states an error "unknown statement 'using System.Windows.Forms' ", and I don't know how to resolve it :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you have to save your file with `.cs` extension and invoke a process to compile it using c# compiler `csc.exe`.

After saving the file, you can compile the code using,

```
C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\csc.exe [options] filename.cs
```

Take a look at [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/ms379563(v=vs.80)?redirectedfrom=MSDN) for `options`

You can invoke a process to do this from your IDE.

```
System.Diagnostics.Process process = new System.Diagnostics.Process();
System.Diagnostics.ProcessStartInfo startInfo = new System.Diagnostics.ProcessStartInfo();
startInfo.WindowStyle = System.Diagnostics.ProcessWindowStyle.Hidden;
startInfo.FileName = "cmd.exe";
startInfo.Arguments = "C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\csc.exe filename.cs";
process.StartInfo = startInfo;
process.Start();
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Hi, Nishan! I liked your code a whole lot, but I was wondering.. How would I then start the compiled .exe? I tested, and it compiles. But I can't find the output .exe ...

Comment: Is it not in the same folder that your `.cs` file is in?

Comment: I don't think it was generated :( It should be in the same folder as my current project(that's where I saved it) but it's not .. Any idea how to fix?

Comment: I have a `MenuStrip` `Item` that is displayed "Compile Winforms C#", and when it is pressed, no errors occur(with the code you gave me.) ...But, it doesn't start the newly compiled app, and it doesn't even generate it, from what I see in the folder :(

Comment: Try to provide options to specify output `C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\csc.exe /target:exe /out:filename.exe filename.cs`

Comment: I did - Still nothing :(

Answer (score 1):

Finally, after many, many times of struggling, I got it to work :) **With the help of [Nishan Chathuranga](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5260872/nishan-chathuranga)**

```
        string compiledOutput = "Generated.exe";

        //COMPILATION WORK
        String[] referenceAssemblies = { "System.dll", "System.Drawing.dll", "System.Windows.Forms.dll" };

        CodeDomProvider _CodeCompiler = CodeDomProvider.CreateProvider("CSharp");
        System.CodeDom.Compiler.CompilerParameters _CompilerParameters =
         new System.CodeDom.Compiler.CompilerParameters(referenceAssemblies, "");

        _CompilerParameters.OutputAssembly = compiledOutput;
        _CompilerParameters.GenerateExecutable = true;
        _CompilerParameters.GenerateInMemory = false;
        _CompilerParameters.WarningLevel = 3;
        _CompilerParameters.TreatWarningsAsErrors = true;
        _CompilerParameters.CompilerOptions = "/optimize /target:winexe";//!! HERE IS THE SOLUTION !!

        string _Errors = null;
        try
        {
            // Invoke compilation
            CompilerResults _CompilerResults = null;
            _CompilerResults = _CodeCompiler.CompileAssemblyFromSource(_CompilerParameters, richTextBox1.Text);

            if (_CompilerResults.Errors.Count > 0)
            {
                // Return compilation errors
                _Errors = "";
                foreach (System.CodeDom.Compiler.CompilerError CompErr in _CompilerResults.Errors)
                {
                    _Errors += "Line number " + CompErr.Line +
                    ", Error Number: " + CompErr.ErrorNumber +
                    ", '" + CompErr.ErrorText + ";\r\n\r\n";
                }
            }
        }
        catch (Exception _Exception)
        {
            // Error occurred when trying to compile the code
            _Errors = _Exception.Message;
        }



        //AFTER WORK
        if (_Errors == null)
        {
            // lets run the program
            MessageBox.Show(compiledOutput + " Compiled !");
            System.Diagnostics.Process.Start(compiledOutput);
        }
        else
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Error occurred during compilation : \r\n" + _Errors);
        }
```

- This works like a **charm!**